# Log4J Swing Appender

Tags: java, swing, log4j

I need to append log4j content to a Swing component (JTextArea or similar).  Is there a common way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of introducing an external library, I ended up editing the log4j.properties file to include the following:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, app
log4j.appender.app=path.to.class.extending.WriterAppender
```

Then I employed an observer pattern to post the data into my GUI's JTextArea.

Comment: Did you only overwrite the WriterAppender.append() method?

Comment: Please, can you give an example of how you did it? This is still valid today

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Google, I've obviously discovered the [Log4j-Swing-Appender](http://code.google.com/p/log4j-swing-appender/).

Comment: Log4j swing appender works great for me as well. It nicely keeps the scrollbar at the bottom (no jumping), and if user scrolls back, it lets the user view without moving the scrollbar. If user again moves the scrollbar to the button, it starts autoscrolling again - great!

Answer (score 4):

to make the JScrollPane wrapping the target component (e.g. JTextArea) automatically scroll down to show the latest log entries, consider calling:

```
  org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LF5SwingUtils.makeVerticalScrollBarTrack(scrollPane);
```