# There is an interface/GUI appender for log4j?

Tags: java, log4j, appender

I want to show my logs in the GUI in a textfield, list, etc. (something like ImgBurn), but I not found a ready appender that do this. There are an appender to do this?

Currently I doing log to the console without any problems.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358926/log4j-swing-appender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Apache Chainsaw: this can use the Receiver concept from the recent Log4j builds to display events: http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html.

If you are looking to do real-time text field display you may need to write your own Receiver class.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good tools available for Free (paid as well) that can parse your log files and present them in better formats with lots of filtering and reporting options as well.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j#Log_Viewers) is a good list of such tools

Are you looking for a real time log viewer?

Comment: Yes, i want to see the logs while the application is running.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you [OtrosLogViewr](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/). It can tail logs from running applications even on remote servers (using SFTP, FTP, Samba)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the latest developer snapshot of Chainsaw - tons of new features, and when configured to process log files via VFSLogFilePatternReceiver, can tail log files, even between app restarts.

There are a ton of new features in this version compared with the currently-released one - some of the more helpful include search results that are highlighted and aggregated in a table, and the ability to annotate events (click in the 'marker' field)

http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Answer (score 0):

Try Glasswall, which appends the log contents on the page if you are running a servlet.

http://code.google.com/p/glasswall/